# Zipping a binary file in python

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to include a binary file within a zip file and below is the code snippet:
I first unzip the zip contents into a temporary location and add few more files and zip it back to a new archive.

```py
import zipfile


def test(fileName, tempDir):
    # unzip the file contents,may contain binary files
    myZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, "r")
    for name in myZipFile.namelist():
        toFile = tempDir + "/" + name
        fd = open(toFile, "w")
        fd.write(myZipFile.read(name))
        fd.close()
    myZipFile.close()
    # code which post processes few of the files goes here

    # zip it back
    newZip = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, mode="w")
    try:
        fileList = os.listdir(tempDir)
        for name in fileList:
            name = tempDir + "/" + name
            newZip.write(name, os.path.basename(name))
        newZip.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Exception occured while writing to PAR file: " + fileName)
```

Some of the files may be binary files. The zipping code works fine but when i try to unzip it using linux ' unzip or python's zip module , i get the below error:

> zipfile corrupt.   (please check that you have transferred or
> created the zipfile in the   appropriate BINARY mode and that you have
> compiled UnZip properly)

And am using python 2.3

What's going wrong here ?

Comment: Looks pretty much right to me. Tested with Python3 + minimal changes and works.

Comment: Works in Python 2.7 too. Either it is a bug in 2.3, or some other error - did you try to open it with different zip programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm not sure if its a bug in python 2.3. Current work environment do not allow me to upgrade to a higher version of python :-( :-( :-(

The below workaround worked:

```
import zipfile

def test(fileName, tempDir):
    # unzip the file contents,may contain binary files
    myZipFile=zipfile.ZipFile(fileName,'r')
    for name in myZipFile.namelist(): 
        toFile = tempDir + '/' + name

        # check if the file is a binary file
        #if binary file, open it in "wb" mode
            fd = open(toFile, "wb")
        #else open in just "w" mode
            fd = open(toFile, "w")

        fd.write(myZipFile.read(name))
        fd.close()
    myZipFile.close()
    # code which post processes few of the files goes here

    #zip it back
    newZip = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, mode='w')
    try:
        fileList = os.listdir(tempDir)
        for name in fileList:
            name = tempDir + '/' + name
            newZip.write(name,os.path.basename(name))
        newZip.close()
    except Exception:
            print 'Exception occured while writing to PAR file: ' + fileName
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to upgrade, as Python 2.3 is really outdated. 2.7.3 is the latest one from the 2.x-versions and 3.2.3 the latest python version.

See [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall):

```
 |  extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None)
 |      Extract all members from the archive to the current working
 |      directory. `path' specifies a different directory to extract to.
 |      `members' is optional and must be a subset of the list returned
 |      by namelist().
```

(New in version 2.6)

Take a look at [Zip a folder and its content](http://snipplr.com/view/19640/zip-a-folder-and-its-content/).

You might also be interested in [distutlis.archive_util](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.archive_util).